# What tap do I need for this application?

Tags: pipe, tools, shelf

I have some wire shelving units that I would like to extend the poles on to make them taller. The shelves are composed of two vertical poles that are female threaded on one end. The poles are connected with a connector that is male threaded on both ends. Unfortunately, the poles are only threaded on one end, so I need to find a way to put threads on the unthreaded side of other poles I have. (the photo with the green arrow shows what I am trying to thread).

I don't have any experience doing taps, and I cannot figure out how to determine the size tap I need. I found a lot of charts for various drills required for a tap, but nothing that links them to the size of the 'hole' or pipe being drilled(someone needs to create a simple calculator!). I don't even know if it is metric or not; the ads for the shelves (they are all pretty standard) say "1 inch poles" but any tap I found at 1 inch was either 8 or 12 TPI, and these are closer to 16 (or they are metric). Even more confusing, the connectors say 'coarse' thread. The connectors also are described as having a pitch of 1.5 mm.

The closest I can figure is maybe a M23x1.5? Is the diameter of the tap the same as the interior pipe dimension?

Also, if I'm tapping by hand, would a 'plug' tap be the right one to get?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any chance you can get the components from the original manufacturer? My tap set has a thread guage tool (multiple blades with various thread pitches/depths) but nothing I have in the mechanics set has a tap large enough to handle that. Perhaps a contractor who installs natural gas pipes could help you out, but I have no idea how you would hold the connector material with the threads that close

Comment: Rather than complicated connectors, why not take a 2' dowel, sized snug and pinned in place with a through bolt?

Comment: No luck on the original manufacturer, they (and other resellers) just sell the poles, and they all seem to be made the same way, threaded on only one side (even though that makes little sense from a SKU/inventory perspective).

Comment: Regarding the dowel: I did think of that, but have not been able to find a dowel to fit tighly enough. I'd also have to drill the holes, but that I'm sure would be easier than the tapping...

I'm rather surprised I couldn't find information on this, since there must be tens of millions of these shelves in use, and I know others have search a lot of extending the height.

Comment: When they fall over or collapse in their newly extended, less stable version; and hurt someone, the manufacturer not providing double-threaded versions will be very useful to them in court proving that the liability for that is entirely on you for making unapproved modifications to their product.

Comment: I understand your point, but I'm not sure they will be less stable, since you can buy other versions of the shelves that are taller and connect the same way. I assume they have only one side threaded to make it easier/cheaper to attach the top pole cover (snap in) and on the bottom, the legs or casters (i.e. they save the cost of doing the threading). 
Leaving all that aside, I'm still terribly ignorant of how to figure out what size tap to use for any given application.

Comment: Sure seems like the easy button would be to just buy a shelving unit that comes with longer vertical struts.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is facing a similar type problem, this was the answer:

I used a M23 x 1.5 pitch tap.In other words, the tap is the diameter of the interior of the pipe, which is 23 mm. The threads looked good, but I had a little problem getting the threaded connector started, so after some trial and error I used a slightly larger tap to make about half a thread. (It was actually a 1 inch SAE coarse 8 threads/inch, which isn't the right pitch, but it was just enough to allow the connected to engage). The connectors fit nice and snug, as did the poles.

I estimated that I saved over $500 doing this by not buying longer poles, and even more if I replaced the entire shelving units. In both cases I would have had either poles or shelves I could not use and would have had to trash them, which I hate doing.

Thanks for all who made suggestions.